# Which punctuation is best for connecting the latter longer clause in this sentence, or is the comma splice okay?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, dashes, comma-splices

I am proofreading a colleague's work. And I know that you should use a connective/conjunction to join two clauses together rather than a comma splice, and so, in the past I have made such corrections as in **example 1** below. However, **example 2** is what I'm uncertain about. It feels wrong to use a dash. I believe a dash is used to add a short little extra thought to the end of a sentence, and a semicolon doesn't feel so right either. Is the comma splice okay to have in **example 2**?

**Example 1**

**Error:** He gives good answers in his workbooks and tests, he just needs to check his grammar.

**Correction:** He gives good answers in his workbooks and tests – he just needs to check his grammar.   (though sometimes I wonder if it should be a semicolon instead)

**Example 2**

**Error?:** Jaonaay is an active student, only his energy is focused more on playful learning rather than in-depth understanding of concepts.

**Correction?**: Jaonaay is an active student ... (**dash, semicolon, comma?**) ... only his energy is focused more on playful learning rather than in-depth understanding of concepts.

Comment: Do people still use colons to link contrasting statements? It's largely a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Huddleston & Pullum (2002), when *only* is used in this way (to mean "but"), it behaves in some respects like a coordinator and in some ways like a preposition with a clausal complement, though they think it is best placed in the latter category (pp. 1321-1322). In more traditional terminology, you could call it a subordinating conjunction, similar to *although.*

So, in your example 2, "his energy [...] concepts" is a subordinate clause; the sentence therefore does not contain a comma splice.

**Edit:** Making it a separate sentence would likely cause readers to interpret it differently. People would interpret the sentence "Only his energy is focused..." as "His energy, and nothing else, is focused..."

Comment: Oxford Languages (google 'only meaning') 'has << **only** conjunction [informal]: 
except that; but.
• _He is still a young man, only he seems older because of his careworn expression_. >> I'd say 'only' can be treated wrt punctuation just like 'but' here (preceding comma, dash or ellipsis; full stop and new 'sentence'). There remains the problem of register. Is it too informal in OP's example?

Answer (score 0):

Just to supply some readily available sources in support of alphabet's answer - almost all dictionaries have it as a conjunction, so no error.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/only)

> only
>
> conjunction
>
> 1 a : with the restriction that : but *you may go, only
> come back early*
>
> b : and yet : however *they look very nice, only we
> can't use them*
>
> 2 : were it not that : except *I'd introduce you to her,
> only you'd win her— Jack London*

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=only)

> conj.
>
> 1.Were it not that; except that: *We would have reached the summit, only the weather got bad*.
>
> 2.a. With the restriction that; but: *You may go, only be careful*.
>
> b. However; and yet: *The merchandise is well made, only we can't use
> it.*

etc.